# How to generate following error distributions? (contaminated normal distribution, A normal heteroscedastic distribution

Tags: r, regression

[3] A contaminated normal distribution, 0.9 × N(0,1) + 0.1 × N(0, 102), i.e., the standard normal distribution N(0, 1) contaminated by N(0, 102), a normal distribution with a much larger variance. This distribution has C95=3.07.

[4] A normal heteroscedastic distribution, N(0,x2i). We will consider skewed error distributions in Simulation B. To simulate data under each parameter setting, we first generated xi from the standard normal distribution; then conditional on the values of xi, we simulated mi and yi according to equations 17 and 18. Without loss of generality, we assumed that β02 = β03 = 0 for convenience.

mi = β02 + αxi + e2i    (17)

yi = β03 + βmi + τ′xi + e3i, (18)

I'm trying to generate two error distributions based on the paragraph above; a contaminated normal distribution and a normal heteroscedastic distribution.

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: you don't add the components in [1], you choose between them with the specified probabilities. It's not clear what you're trying to say with [2]. Your question is very hard to follow, please include more context, better layout and pay attention to writing clear sentences

Comment: Sorry Glen. I just edited my question and add extra info. I'm new to R.  I don't know how to choose between components with the specified probabilities. would it be possible to show me how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to your first question, as mentioned by @Glen_b, you could use e.g.:

```
 cont_norm <- function(n, # number of samples
                      mu = 0, # only one mu since the mean is the same for both distributions. 
                      sd1 = 1, # sd of the first distr
                      sd2 = 102, # sd of the second distr
                      prob = 0.1 # contamination proportion
                      ){
  s <- sample(c(sd1, sd2), n, replace = T, prob = c(1 - prob, prob))
rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = s)}

cont_norm(100, mu = 0, sd1 = 1, sd2 = 102, prob = 0.1)
```

I'm not sure about the second case, since some details are missing in your description. What's β02 in Eq 17?

Comment: Thank you very much for the example ed_sans:). It helps me a lot!  oh  and sorry, β02  in equation 17 is assumed to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

[3] There's several ways to do it. One way is to `sample` a length-n vector (with replacement) from the two choices of variance (converted to standard deviations) with specified probabilities, and supply that vector of sd's to `rnorm`. See `?sample` and `rnorm`.

[4] you literally supply the vector of indicated standard deviations (again, after you convert the given variances) to `rnorm`

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much for explanation! Glen :). sorry that I gave you incomplete information. It is because of a lack of understanding of statistic.I didn't fully understand what [4] is talk about.  I'm trying to learn R by myself now, but it seems like I  need to learn stat first.